# Generating a simple separator line for textview

Tags: android, textview

I have made this simple notification application which has a single textview to display a text message received from push notification . Every time a user receives a notification its appended to the textviews text field .

The current format in which my textview display notifications is like following

```
14 may 2014
message text one here

16 may 2014
message text two here

17 may 2014
message text three here
```

The format I want to display is like the following

```
14 may 2014
message text one here
_______________________
16 may 2014
message text two here
_______________________
17 may 2014
message text three here
_______________________
```

Now I can append the textview with the string '-----------' but this will not work with phones of all sizes and the output will be garbled like following

```
 14 may 2014
    message text one here
    __________________
    _____
    16 may 2014
    message text two here
    ___________________
    ____
    17 may 2014
    message text three here
    __________________
    _____
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to measure width of the "dash/underscore" char and calculate appropriate amount of chars. So do not reinvent the wheel. Use standard [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html).